# Submit 'int' and 'string' arrays using ctypes (Python->C++)

Tags: python, ctypes

I've a simple working program that submits an `int` (`num_piezas`in the example) from a `Python` function to a `C++` function.

**foo.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo{
    public:
        void bar(int number){
            printf("Number is: %d\n", number);
        }
};

extern "C" {
    Foo* Foo_new(){ return new Foo(); }
    void Foo_bar(Foo* foo, int number){ foo->bar(number); }
}
```

**fooWrapper.py**

```
from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libfoo.so')

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = lib.Foo_new()

    def bar(self, num_piezas):
        lib.Foo_bar(self.obj, num_piezas)

num_piezas = 5    
f = Foo()
f.bar(num_piezas)
```

The thing is that now I want to send an `int` array and a `char` array along with that number. So I tried:

**foo.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

class Foo{
    public:
        void bar(int number, int piezas[3], char prioridades[3][20]){
            printf("Number is: %d\n", number);
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++) {
                printf("%d", piezas[i]);
            }
            for(int q=0;q<3;q++) {
                printf("%s ", prioridades[q]);
            }
        }
};

extern "C" {
    Foo* Foo_new(){ return new Foo(); }
    void Foo_bar(Foo* foo, int number, int piezas[3], char prioridades[3][20]){ foo->bar(number, piezas, prioridades); }
}
```

**fooWrapper.py**

```
from ctypes import cdll
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./libfoo.so')

class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.obj = lib.Foo_new()

    def bar(self, num_piezas, piezas, prioridades):
        lib.Foo_bar(self.obj, num_piezas, piezas, prioridades)

piezas = [1, 2, 3]
prioridades = ['normal', 'baja', 'primera pieza']
num_piezas = 5    
f = Foo()
f.bar(num_piezas, piezas, prioridades)
```

The `C++` file compiles correctly, but when I try to execute the Python function (`python fooWrapper.py`) this error message shows up:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "fooWrapper.py", line 15, in <module>
>     f.bar(num_piezas, piezas, prioridades)
>   File "fooWrapper.py", line 9, in bar
>     lib.Foo_bar(self.obj, num_piezas, piezas, prioridades)
> ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 3
> ```

What I'm doing wrong? Do I need to do something else to pass that `int` and `string` arrays as parameters? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

You can get away with this modification :

```
from ctypes import c_int, c_char

...

# create a 3-int array
piezas = (c_int*3)()
piezas[0] = 1
piezas[1] = 2
piezas[2] = 3

# create a 3-(20-char array) array
prio = ((c_char*20)*3)()
prio[0].value = "normal"
prio[1].value = "baja"
prio[2].value = "primera pieza"
```

But since you're dealing with char arrays in the C++ side part, I would advise you to change your function defintion for : `void Bar( int num, char* piezas, int len_piezas, char** prio , int len_prio_elem, int prio);`. It is much longer, but you have to control the length of the input arrays if you want to avoid buffer overflows.

Comment: you're right. I did propose a quick fix to solve OP's problem, but it is hackish at best. I will write a proper solution after my shift.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define a function prototype using CFUNCTYPE (read the docs), then wrap your function using new type, after that you will get typed function. You have to do that every time you want to use c-function with args or return type different from int.

http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#function-prototypes

http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#callback-functions

Python lists and c arrays are different. You can define c-array type in python, read here:

http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#arrays